# It is possible for a matrix to not have eigenvalues? If it's possible, what does it mean?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to solve differential systems of equations. My system is homogeneous with the form

$$Y'(x)=\pmatrix {0 &1 \\ -5 &-4}Y(x)$$

I have been asked to obtain the fundamental matrix of the system. How could I do this?

Comment: Pathologically, the $0\times 0$ matrix has no eigenvalues. -- Otherwise, the existence of eigenvalues may depend on the scalar field (e.g., there may not be a real eigenvalue, but complex ones)

Comment: An $n\times n$-matrix has always exactly $n$ eigenvalues (counted with multiplicities). It needs to be a square matrix though.

Comment: @M.Winter Even over a finite field?

Comment: The title and the body do not match.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Only over an algebraically closed field, so not for finite fields. But I suspect that OP is talking about real matrices, hopefully accepting complex numbers for the eigenvalues. Otherwise my statement is not true.